# How do I check .net/mono version from within .net

Tags: .net

I have a .net application that runs under both the MS implementation and Mono. It requires .net 4.5 and also won't run on old versions of Mono (e.g. it's broken under 3.8.0, whereas 3.10.0 is fine).

I thought a good way of checking whether the application can run would be to write a short bit of code that can link against .net 2.0 libraries, and do the checks there. That way it's easy to determine the Mono version, and I can re-use the same code in the main application as a safety check (though it may not get as far as executing that code - e.g. the application just exists without saying anything under .net 4.0).

The problem I have is finding the highest version of .net that is supported under whatever runtime is being used to execute the test code, as opposed to whatever version it was linked against (which seems to be what System.Environment.Version returns). I can get the version of Mono by using reflection to execute Mono.Runtime.GetDisplayName. Perhaps there is some (similar?) solution that would work under Windows .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows the most reliable way to determine the installed .NET framework version is to use the registry. The subkey you need to check is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\
```

Check out this link for a sample of code to read these values correctly in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In Mono the most reliable way to determine the version is probably by running the shell command:

```
mono --version
```

I guess you could run that with the `Process` class and parse the output.

Comment: Many thanks for the link to MS documentation. (Calling mono is not easy because it requires knowing where the executable came from. But the reflection-based method I mentioned works for me.)

Comment: So does this answer your question, or you need additional suggestions?